# When using ctypes libc.strlen always returning 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a simple code using ctypes:

```
Python 3.1.1 (r311:74480, Feb 23 2010, 11:06:41)
[GCC 4.1.2 20071124 (Red Hat 4.1.2-42)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
>>> libc.strlen("HELLO")
1
>>> print(libc.strlen("HELLO"))
1
```

What did I do wrong ?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 uses Unicode for strings. When passed to a C function those will be more than one byte per character, and for ASCII characters one of those bytes will be zero. `strlen` will stop at the first zero it finds.

I'm able to duplicate these results in Python 2.7, along with a fix:

```
>>> libc.strlen("HELLO")
5
>>> libc.strlen(u"HELLO")
1
>>> libc.strlen(u"HELLO".encode('ascii'))
5
```

Answer (score 2):

With `ctypes` it is a good idea to tell it the types of the arguments, and it will tell you when you get them wrong:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, 07:15:24) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> libc = ctypes.CDLL("msvcrt")
>>> libc.strlen('hello')
1
>>> libc.strlen.argtypes=[ctypes.c_char_p]
>>> libc.strlen('hello')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type
```

In Python 3, strings are default Unicode.  `b''` syntax are byte strings, which is what strlen works on:

```
>>> libc.strlen(b'hello')
5
```

On Windows at least, there are wide versions of strlen:

```
>>> libc.wcslen.argtypes=[ctypes.c_wchar_p]
>>> libc.wcslen('hello')
5
```

Comment: Thanks Mark for your explanation!.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 20 2012, 22:39:59)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ctypes
>>> libc = ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6')
>>> libc.strlen('HELLO')
5
```

Either your version of Python or gcc or perhaps it needs to be explicitly NUL terminated as in `libc.strlen('HELLO\0')` ?

Answer (score 0):

Strange....with b it works!.

```
>>> libc.strlen(b'HELLO')
5
```

Comment: Python 3 uses Unicode strings by default, and iirc CPython stores its Unicode strings in UTF-16 encoding (or a variant) under the cover, so that might be the problem. (Even though string literals are supposed to be encoded by the encoding set for the interpreter, which if I'm not mistaken is normally UTF-8 on *nix systems.)