# How to determine the length of a NULL-terminated string with ctypes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes, null-terminated

I am accessing a function through `ctypes` which returns a pointer to a NULL-terminated string (array/vector of chars). The memory is allocated by the function (not under my control). The problem is, it does not return any information on its length. What I came up with (and what works), loosely inspired by what I would do in C, looks a bit wacky:

```
import ctypes

def get_length_of_null_terminated_string(in_pointer):
    datatype = ctypes.c_char
    datatype_size = ctypes.sizeof(datatype)
    terminator = b'\x00'
    length = 0
    char_pointer = ctypes.cast(in_pointer, ctypes.POINTER(datatype))
    STRING_MAX = 1024
    while True:
        if char_pointer.contents.value == terminator:
            break
        if length > STRING_MAX:
            raise
        void_pointer = ctypes.cast(char_pointer, ctypes.c_void_p)
        void_pointer.value += datatype_size
        char_pointer = ctypes.cast(void_pointer, ctypes.POINTER(datatype))
        length += 1
    return length

def test():
    test_string = b'Hello World!'
    print('Actual length: %d' % len(test_string))
    test_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(test_string)
    test_pointer = ctypes.cast(test_buffer, ctypes.c_void_p)
    print('Measured length: %d' % get_length_of_null_terminated_string(test_pointer))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Is there a better way of doing it?

In particular, I can not find a way to get rid of the two `cast` statements. It appears that I can only increment the address of a `c_void_p` object (through its `value` attribute) while the same seems to be impossible for a pointer to `c_char`.

Comment: I assume it's too expensive to just call `strlen()`?

Comment: @TrippKinetics It is not ... I was looking for a way of doing it with Python / ctypes - have I overlooked something in the documentation?

Comment: Why do you need the length? Shouldn't ctypes handle converting the string itself?

Comment: Use libc.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022571/when-using-ctypes-libc-strlen-always-returning-1

Comment: If you have a `c_char_p` pointing to a NULL-terminate string, `len(c_char_p.value)` will do it.

Comment: Even if you have something different, like a `POINTER(c_uint8)`, you can `cast` it as easily as you can iterate it, and you don't have to fight against `ctypes` trying to discourage accidental pointer arithmetic or trying to convert to `bytes` against your will.

Comment: @abarnert `c_char_p` is the way to go, thanks. I was experimenting with `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)`, which did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @abarnert for suggesting this in the comments.

Working with `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)` is sort of the wrong approach here. Casting my pointer to `ctypes.c_char_p` instead helps. Python's `len` method can simply be applied to the `value` attribute of an instance of `c_char_p`.

Along the lines of my original example, a solution would look like this:

```
def get_length_of_null_terminated_string_better(in_pointer):
    return len(ctypes.cast(in_pointer, ctypes.c_char_p).value)
```